# Disable chat room notifications for OSX Messages?

Tags: messages, notifications

In the Mountain Lion Messages app, is there a way to disable notifications for *chat room* messages, but still have notifications for private messages? (this is the default behavior in Adium)

Answer (score 1):

With the chatroom thread selected, uncheck **Use Alerts in this Conversation** from the **View** menu.

The is the best solution I've found (only disables notifications on a per thread basis).  I haven't found a global setting that disables notifications for all chatrooms.

<sup>I found the solution from [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/103880) on ["How do I temporarily disable or mute Messages (iMessage) on OS X?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52995/how-do-i-temporarily-disable-or-mute-messages-imessage-on-os-x)</sup>